# Merge Replication: Are multiple publications better than one big one?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, replication, merge-replication

We have merge replication set up in SQL Server 2000.  One of our publications has 65 articles in it.  This works fine but it is a hassle to modify anything (beyond adding a column via `sp_repladdcolumn`) because it takes quite a long time to regenerate the snapshot.  I'd always accepted this as a necessary evil until I came across this quote in a [forum discussing replication](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-replication/2188/Cannot-drop-the-table-because-it-is-being-used-for#slrnc4r8v8pmdmajkflysrkferhr):

> Do you have all of you tables
>   publicated in one publication? If
>   that's the case, you should reconsider
>   your replication design.

So should we reconsider *our* replication design?  **What are the pros and cons of splitting our single publication into multiple publications with fewer articles?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with SQL2000 replication and little experience with merge replication, but there's a setting for transactional publications called immediate_sync that controls whether all articles are generated when the snapshot is run or only articles that have uninitialized subscribers.  That would be worth looking into.